# Angularjs ng-repeat "Cannot read proterty of parent" when using in <tr> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I have a Django page and Angular app with the following code:

```
<section id="categoryListServerspage" ng-controller="categoryListServerController">
<data ng-init="ServerList={{ ServerList  }}"/>
<div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
        <h2><a href="#/category/<% CategoryName %>" ng-click="clear()"><% CategoryName %></a> <small>category servers</small></h2>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="x_content">
  <% ServerList %>
    <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Server Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Last hour data insertion</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="servers in ServerList">
            <td>test</td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The `<% ServerList %>` is being rendered but am having undefined variable error in the ng-repeat. It seems as if the ServerList in the ng-repeat is not defined.

> angular1.5.7.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of
>   undefined
>       at Object.enter (angular1.5.7.min.js:202)
>       at angular1.5.7.min.js:301
>       at angular1.5.7.min.js:58
>       at angular1.5.7.min.js:62
>       at d (angular1.5.7.min.js:59)
>       at n (angular1.5.7.min.js:64)
>       at angular1.5.7.min.js:301
>       at angular1.5.7.min.js:141
>       at m.$digest (angular1.5.7.min.js:142)
>       at m.$apply (angular1.5.7.min.js:145)

In my controller I can access the scope variable ServerList however:

```
$scope.$watch('ServerList', function () {
        console.log($scope.ServerList); 
    });
```

**ERRATA:**

Whats is bizare is ng-repeat with the same variable with a div is working but not with the `<tr>` tag.

This works:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in ServerList">
      <% x.name %>
    </div>
```

But not this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="servers in ServerList">
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
```

How do I make my ng-repeat work with the `<tr>` tag??

Note: Angular is using tags `<% BLABLA %>` and Django templates is using `{{ }}`

**Update:**

ServerList is initialized with the following :

> [{"name":"TestServer","status":"Active","dns":"testserver.devlocal","category_id":21,"location":"AF"},{"name":"Tserver2","status":"Active","dns":"Tserver2.devlocal","category_id":21,"location":"DZ"}]

It is interpreted as an object:

```
$scope.$watch('ServerList', function () {
        console.log(typeof($scope.ServerList)); 
    });
```

Returns object.

Comment: what does ServerList contain? you have to check if it is treated as an array or a simple string

Comment: @coding-dude.com It is of type Object. Please check Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out my mistake. Its a clear example of mixing Jquery and Angular JS.

I had `$('#datatable-responsive').DataTable();` in my controller which prevented the `ng-repeat` to work well.

So i waited Angular to repeat the `<tr>` tags and execute a function once done with the help of custom `repeat-done` directive:

`<tr ng-repeat="servers in ServerList" repeat-done>`

I created a directive as Follows:

```
app.directive('repeatDone', function () {
    return {

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
          $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable();
        }
    };
});
```